# Cut cells within a named range, containing a specific value and paste them to specified column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, named-ranges

i have multiple rows that contain multiple columns of data, the data in each row is almost the same but the columns are in different orders.

What im trying to do is to align all of the data in the columns with the other rows so that each column contain the same value, maybe a screen shot will help explain better.
Here is an example.
[image: screenshot of current excel sheet]
This is only a small section but the sheet has many more columns and rows, i have named all active cells with a named range (allcells44), this is the area where i want to search.

I have managed to successfully complete this task which has taken me 2 days to put together through trial and error but i'm running multiple subs (254 subs together) all in one module which is extremely long and it is taking some time complete. here is what i have at the moment

```
Sub Findandcut1()

Dim row As Long

For row = 1 To 267
    ' Check if "att_base_name" appears in the value anywhere.
    If Range("I" & row).Value Like "*att_base_name:*" Then
        ' Copy the value to the destination column.
        Range("I" & row).Cut
        ' move the original data in column to the right.
        Range("H" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If
Next

Call Findandcut2

End Sub

Sub Findandcut2()

Dim row As Long

For row = 1 To 267
    ' Check if "att_base_name" appears in the value anywhere.
    If Range("J" & row).Value Like "*att_base_name:*" Then
        ' Copy the value to the destination column.
        Range("J" & row).Cut
        ' move the original data in column to the right.
        Range("H" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If
Next

Call Findandcut3

End Sub

Sub Findandcut3()

Dim row As Long

For row = 1 To 267
    ' Check if "att_base_name" appears in the value anywhere.
    If Range("K" & row).Value Like "*att_base_name:*" Then
        ' Copy the value to the destination column.
        Range("K" & row).Cut
        ' move the original data in column to the right.
        Range("H" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If
Next

Call Findandcut4

End Sub
```

This is only a small section of the vba code but it is just repeating it self and changing a few variables each time, so here is one section without calling the next sub.
This is what i have.

```
Sub Findandcut1()

Dim row As Long

For row = 1 To 267
    ' Check if "att_base_name" appears in the value anywhere.
    If Range("I" & row).Value Like "*att_base_name:*" Then
        ' Copy the value to the destination column.
        Range("I" & row).Cut
        ' move the original data in column to the right.
        Range("H" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

And This is what i want

```
Sub Findandcut1()

Dim row As Long

For row = 1 To 267
    ' Check if "att_base_name" appears in the value anywhere.
    If Range("allcells44").Value Like "*att_base_name:*" Then
        ' Copy the value to the destination column.
        Range("allcells44").Cut
        ' move the original data in column to the right.
        Range("H" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

so i want to be able to search all cells in "named range" for value, Then cut and paste them to the specified column, but every variation i try seems to break my code, any help please. Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from the spreadsheet image and your code, but do you have a constant set of prefixes to the values in each cell, or are those prefixes dynamic.  Does every row include a cell with each prefix?

Comment: Instead of rearranging the cells in the sheet, can you simply create a new sheet with the data in the proper order?

Comment: @STLDev the prefixes are constant but a handful of rows are missing some of the data & prefix completely. The first seven columns are already in order and don’t have a prefix. Regarding a new sheet, I receive the data in the format that it’s in (unordered), so if you have some recommendation on how I would move the data to a new sheet in the correct order I would be very grateful. Also if you would like I can upload the csv file to web server and put a link to it so you have a better idea of the data. Thanks

Comment: @Michael... your image server account has been banned. Could you upload again?

Comment: i have added a new screenshot with more information showing in my original post

Comment: So still can’t manage to do it the way that I wanted but I have a solution (it’s a messy one) that can move the data to a new sheet or move it to the same sheet but it involves searching each column individually, If I still have no luck over the next couple of days I will post my solution. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If "allcells44" is already an range you could try the following:

```
For row = 1 To 267
    allcells44.Find("*" & att_base_name & ":*")
    If Not allcells44 Is Nothing Then
        allcells44.Find("*" & att_base_name & ":*").Copy 'copy the value
        allcells44.Find("*" & att_base_name & ":*").Insert Shift:=xlToRight 'move the original data
    End if
Next row
```

I'm hoping i got your question right...

Comment: Hi thanks for helping I’m just booting up now and going to give it a go, I will be back shortly with my results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, iv tried it and I'm getting (run-time error '424': Object required, this is highlighting the second line of your code on debug. Thanks Again

Comment: hi I’ve tried loads of different variations of your code nothing seems to work, but it seems to be missing the function to paste to a specific column

Comment: Hi, indeed it is missing the function to paste, i will try to fix it shortly.
Is the error 424 solved already?

Comment: im not having the 424 error come up at all now but i have approached it in a different way which is working and doing the job but still not the way i set out originally in the question.